# Accessing FSCalendar function inside custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, fscalendar

I have a `FSCalendar` view within a `UICollectionViewCell` which is connected and functional. However, when calling the didSelect date function within an extension of the viewController nothing is actioned (the print function is not called). Is a specific reference required to be passed to CellForIndexPath to call this function?

Extension Code:

```
extension CalendarViewController: FSCalendarDelegate, FSCalendarDataSource {

    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {

    print("Date selected")
    }
}
```

Custom Cell:

```
class ChartCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: FSCalendar!

}
```

CollectionView cellForItemAt code:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "chartCell", for: indexPath) as! ChartCollectionViewCell

            return cell
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line inside `cellForItemAt`

```
cell.calendarView.delegate = self
```